# How to use WTForms FormField with additional parameters?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I've got form LimitForm with parameter resource

```
class LimitForm(FlaskForm):
        def __init__(self, resource: Resource, *args, **kwargs):
           super(LimitForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.period.choices = Period.choices()
```

I would like to use this form in other form as field through FormField. Like a

```
class LimitsForm(FlaskForm)
   limits = FieldList(FormField(LimitForm))
```

but this code raises exception **TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'resource'**

How can I pass resource to LimitForm from LimitsForm?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show me the exact code which raise this exception ?

Comment: @RajaSimon https://gist.github.com/skeeph/049a3c5d3fa96f1306c35b492be42b8e

Comment: Oh please update your question instead of the link. I meant to look into your view function

Answer (score 1):

You may find is easier to perform some additional logic after the normal initialization of the enclosing class, e.g. implement you own `LimitsForm.__init__()` with special logic at the end. Otherwise, you will likely have to subclass `FieldList` and `FormField` and override their `process` methods and life will become complicated for you if all you need to do is a simple extra step for one use case!

For example, I have a case where I want to do something similar to what you request and pass some special kwargs through a `FormField`. Flask-WTF does not seem to do this by default. In this case I am using a `QuerySelectField` that I want to pass some special filter through to when I call SQLAlchemy.

In my controller, the call to this is like

```
form = CampaignForm(obj=campaign, studio=campaign.studio)
```

Here, the studio is part of a special filter and is only known at run time. However, this `studio` kwarg does not make it through the nested `FormField`.

Because I'd have to extend and rewire core logic in Flask-WTF to pass this kwarg through the FormField and into `GatingExtraForm`, my solution to this problem is to do this instead:

```
class GatingExtraForm(FlaskForm):
    class Meta:
        # we do not need CSRF in sub-forms
        csrf = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.set_query(studio=kwargs.get('studio'))

    # when this form is nested in a FormField, the studio kwarg may not be passed to __init__, 
    # therefore we make this method available for some post-initialization.
    def set_query(self, studio=None):
        self.gating_campaign.query = db.query(InAppCampaign).filter(InAppCampaign.active)

        if studio:
            self.gating_campaign.query = self.gating_campaign.query.filter(InAppCampaign.studio == studio)

        self.gating_campaign.query = self.gating_campaign.query.order_by(InAppCampaign.name)

    gating_campaign = QuerySelectField(
        "Gating Campaign",
        get_label='name',
        allow_blank=False,
        validators=[validators.Optional()]
    )
    # additional fields here....

class CampaignForm(FlaskForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # because there is no naive way to pass kwargs through on FormField init, 
        # just do some post init special processing
        self.gating_extra.form.set_query(studio=kwargs.get('studio'))

    # additional fields here....
    gating_extra = FormField(GatingExtraForm)
```

This is a bit of a hack, I'll admit, but sometimes it's a reasonable trade-off for rare use-cases. If it turns out to be a common pattern, then you can go deeper into extending Flask-WTF.